# Python Discord.py Kick Command

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote this when when the version of discord.py was 1.7.3
Now after the version of discord.py 2.0.0 or higher, the kick command stopped working, or there is a changed index in the code, which I can’t understand exactly where the error is, tell me where to change or fix

```
#kick
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Кик', colour = discord.Color.green() )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb.set_author(name = member.name, icon_url= member.avatar_url)
    emb.add_field(name = 'Кик', value = 'кикнул игрока : {}'.format(member.mention))
    emb.set_footer(text = 'Был кикнут администратором {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
    await ctx.send( embed= emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1 )
```

Comment: Discord.py 2.0 changed the way commands are working by using them in a ```tree```.
This means you have to ```sync``` the commands inside the command tree. See [migrating to 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html) for more information.

Comment: This is not accurate, as this is relative only for slash/hybrid commands.

Answer (score 0):

The command is working properly, although you do have a typo error when you were setting the author for the embed. There is no attribute `member.avatar_url`, but instead `member.avatar.url`.

Also, in case the user does **Not** have an avatar, the kick will still be performed, but this command will raise and exception (*AttributeError*). You might want to add a conditional to check for that.

Below is the corrected (and tested) command code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Кик', colour = discord.Color.green() )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb.set_author(name = member.name, icon_url= member.avatar.url)
    emb.add_field(name = 'Кик', value = 'кикнул игрока : {}'.format(member.mention))
    emb.set_footer(text = 'Был кикнут администратором {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
    await ctx.send( embed= emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1 )
```

Below a version with correct (and tested) code also including the check for an avatar:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Кик', colour = discord.Color.green() )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb.set_author(name = member.name, icon_url= member.avatar.url if member.avatar else None)
    emb.add_field(name = 'Кик', value = 'кикнул игрока : {}'.format(member.mention))
    emb.set_footer(text = 'Был кикнут администратором {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
    await ctx.send( embed= emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1 )
```